# iPhone 4 microphone not working in phone calls but working in other apps

Tags: iphone, microphone

People cannot hear me when I make a normal phone call. When I use Skype or Facebook call it works but not during a normal call. 
I have done a phone reset already but didn't work 
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I've expanded your title to attempt to summarise the actual problem. Please try to make your titles as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If it was useful, you do best giving it a vote-up. Voting will learn other people that my answer was useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 2 mics

You have 2 microphones on your iPhone:

1. One for normal calls, this one is broken in your case
2. One for environment sounds. This one is used for video conference calls, video's, sound recordings. This one still works.

My suggestion is to go to [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPhone/iPhone-4-Dock-Connector-GSM-ATT/IF182-009) and replace your dock connecter. This replacement also fixes your mic.